# How can I delete certificate that has specific template?

Tags: powershell, certificate

I have some certificates on Windows. These certs has different templates.

I can get thumbprints:

```
$Certificates = get-childitem cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

I can get templates:

```
$Template = ($Certificates.extensions | where-object{$_.oid.FriendlyName -match "Certificate Template Information"}).format(0)
```

So I want to automate deleting cert that has specific template according to thumbprint with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a `Where-Object` filter:

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\my\ |Where-Object{
  ($TmplExt = $_.Extensions |Where-Object {
    $_.Oid.FriendlyName -match 'Certificate Template'
  }) -and 
  $TmplExt.format(0) -match 'MyTemplateName'
} |Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a bit more complicated.

1. First names might change on based on locale of the system: Stick with the object identifier (OID) values.
2. Depending on weather the certificate request was created from a domain joined machine or not the extension might either have the name or just the OID.

Here is what I use to read the template, preferred with its display name, falling back to the OID, with a AD lookup just in case the name is not synchronized yet:

```
$certificate.Extensions `
    | Where-Object { "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7" -eq $_.Oid.Value } `
    | Select-Object @{ Name = "Name"; Expression = { $_.Format($false) }} `
    | Select-Object @{
      Name = "Name";
      Expression = {
        if($_.Name.IndexOf("(1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.") -eq -1) {
          $oidValue = $_.Name.SubString(`
            $_.Name.IndexOf("=") + 1,
            $_.Name.IndexOf(",") - 1 - $_.Name.IndexOf("="));
          $oidLookUp = `
            (New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.Oid($oidValue))`
              .FriendlyName;
          if($false -eq [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($oidLookUp)){
            $oidLookUp;
          } else {
            try{
              $ConfigContext = `
                ([ADSI]"LDAP://RootDSE").ConfigurationNamingContext;
              $ADSI = [ADSI]"LDAP://CN=Certificate Templates," + `
                "CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,$ConfigContext";
              $oidLookUp = $ADSI.Children `
                | Where-Object { $_.'msPKI-Cert-Template-OID' -eq $oidValue } `
                | Select-Object -ExpandProperty displayName -First 1;
            } catch{ }
            if($false -eq [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($oidLookUp)){
              $oidLookUp;
            } else {
              $oidValue;
            }
          }
        } else {
          $_.Name.SubString(`
            $_.Name.IndexOf("=") + 1, `
            $_.Name.IndexOf("(1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.")
              - 1 
              - $_.Name.IndexOf("="))
        }
      }
    } `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1;
```