# Getting certificate thumbprint with no unique data

Tags: shell, scripting, powershell-4.0

I am using the following powershell search to get 3 certificate thumbprints for a user account.

```
get-childitem -path $certPath | where-object {$_.Subject -match "$Displayname"} | Where-Object {$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList -match "EKU OID"}
```

Two of the certificates have an Enhanced Key Usage that I can easily search for.  One of the certificates does not have an Enhanced Key Usage.  I have tried various comparisons to search for a null value, but all of my searches return the other two certs.  I have tried -match, -notmatch, -like, and -notlike.  Any suggestions on how I can single out this certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the certificate by using the following search parameters

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\my\ |Where-Object{
($TmplExt = $_.Extensions |Where-Object {
$_.Oid.FriendlyName -match 'Certificate Template'}) -and 
$TmplExt.format(0) -match 'MyTemplateName'}
```

I found the example from this post:  [How can I delete certificate that has specific template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917270/how-can-i-delete-certificate-that-has-specific-template)